# run r script using docker kaggle image

Tags: r, windows, docker, containers, kaggle

I am trying to reproduce results of an `R script` on my local `Windows OS` (reproduce the results which it gave on kaggle server). For this someone suggested to use `docker images` to run r script on my local.

I have installed docker and finished the steps to set it up by following instructions given here https://docs.docker.com/windows/step_one/

After installing, I am struggling with on how to create the kaggle R image and run an R script on my local using local resources/data. Can someone please help me with these?

Answer (score 0):

You can load already builded image `rstat` from dockerhub:

```
docker run kaggle/rstats
```

For using your local data you should create volume:

```
docker run -v /you/local/data/path:path/in/docker/container kaggle/rstat
```

Volume binds your local storage with container storage. Also you can create additional volume for output data.

The last line in `rstate` dockerfile is

```
CMD ["R"]
```

It means that R console will be called after container start. Just past your script in terminal (script should use data from mounted volume in container and write result to mounted output volume). After script execution you can stop container. Your output data will be saved on your local machine.

**P.S.** image is giant (6Gb). I never seen before such large docker image.